# Appending a list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter, append

I have a list of hot day temperatures:
54.7, 34.5, 33.9, 37.1, 36.1

So I want to start with a list of temperatures like the one above and then create a new list according to the following rules:

Where a temperature is lower than 30, add ‘Low’ to the new list.
Where a temperature is normal (between 30 and 50 both inclusive), add ‘Normal’ to the new list.
Where a temperature is higher than 50, add ‘High’ to the new list.
For example, the list above would give the following:

['High', 'Normal', 'Normal','Normal', 'Normal']

I'm a noob when it comes to Python, I know I need to append but I can't seem to get the code to work, can anyone help me out with a sample code

apologies, I'm new to Stack Overflow, I hadn't posted my code previously, but here it is, I think I managed to get the output i needed.

EDIT: the problem i'm having some of the results are duplicating. i'm not sure if i've done the conditions part correctly

```
 #initialise the input
hotday_temperatures = [54.7, 34.5, 33.9, 37.1, 36.1]
# initialise the output_list to the empty list
results = []
# for each input_value of the input_list:
for temperature in hotday_temperatures:
    if temperature < 30:
        results.append('Low')
    if temperature >=30 or temperature <=50:
        results.append('Normal')
    if temperature > 50:
        results.append('High')

print(results)
```

Comment: We’re not a code writing service.  May I recommend taking a Python tutorial, or doing some (more) research on the web; there are *lots* of resources. Or, if you need *specific* code help, please post your code with the *exact* problem you’re facing.

Comment: _I hadn't posted my code previously, but here it is, I think I managed to get the output i needed._ - **Why** posting a question when your code does what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using list comprehension:

```
>>> temps = [54.7, 34.5, 33.9, 37.1, 36.1]
>>> ["Low" if t < 30 else "High" if t > 50 else "Normal" for t in temps]
['High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal']
```

The expression `"Low" if t < 30 else "High" if t > 50 else "Normal"` is what produces the correct `Low`/`Normal`/`High` string for a given numeric value `t`.  The `for t in temps` part iterates over each value in `temps`; putting the whole thing in `[]` turns it into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

lot of ways to resolve your problem.

one way : a simple program easy to understant for a beginner

```
tps = [54.7, 34.5, 33.9, 37.1, 36.1]
result = []
for t in tps:
    r = 'Low' if t < 30 else 'High' if t > 50 else 'Normal'
    result.append(r)

print(result)

['High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal']
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, on stack overflow, you'll show the code that you've tried when you ask your question rather than asking for something to be coded from scratch, but here's a solution that would work.

```
list_temps = [54.7, 34.5, 33.9, 37.1, 36.1]
list_desc = []

for temp in list_temps:
    if temp < 30:
        list_desc.append('L')
    elif temp > 50:
        list_desc.append('H')
    else:
        list_desc.append('N')
```

Comment: ahh sorry i'm new to Stack Overflow, I will keep that in mind for next time. But thank you so much

Comment: I think it's been fixed now. Thx @S3DEV